# Bootstraps nav-tabs cross

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs, nav, bootstrap-tabs

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I have the following code:

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-4 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div >
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#login" class="border-radius-0" data-toggle="tab">Sign In</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="#register" class="border-radius-0" data-toggle="tab">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="login" class="tab-pane fade active in">
            <login-form ></login-form>
        </div>
        <div id="register" class="tab-pane fade">
            <register-form></register-form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My UI looks like this. Why is the cross appearing at the end? How do I get rid of it?
[image]

Thanks,
Shilpa

Comment: Cuold you expand `<login-form ></login-form>`?

Comment: You can simply right click the cross and choose "Inspect" in most browsers, then you'll see exactly where the HTML for this is

Comment: reinder - done that. It doesn't show any element.

Comment: @Banzay, login form looks like this.
<div class="panel">
<form>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="row">
<div [class]="emailClass"><!--textbox--></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div [class]="passwordClass"><!--password content--></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg" (click)="l()">Sign In</button>
</div>
<div class="row">
<button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" type="button" (click)="rP()">Reset Password</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>